# PHP Regular expression for North/South/East/West

Tags: php, regex

I have an address: 123 West 1st Street South West #910
What I want to achieve is to extract the words, North, South, East, West, North East, North West and South East and South West.

This is what I did:

```
$address = '123 West 1st Street South West #910';

$array = array('north','south','east','west','north east','north west','south east', 'south west');

foreach ($array as $val) {
    if (preg_match("/$val/i", $address, $match, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE)) {
        //do your stuff here
    }
}
```

With the above code I wanted to get the offset of the whole word "south west" plus the name itself but going through the array I get the last one on the address field which is west.

Your help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to match each one individually, but let the regex engine figure it out. It'll try to get you the longest match first, trying the possibilities in the order you supplied them.

```
(?:(?:north|south)(?:[ ](?:east|west))?|east|west)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/wZ6rU0/1)

Here you get all the possible cases.

Comment: Thanks this worked! Just a note - using option g will result to an error if you used preg_match so use preg_match_all and remove the regex option g.